# how to find entered key code

Tags: c#

how to find entered key code in c# .net page load.i want to check whether the entered key is 'ENTER' key or not.i tried something but not working

```
ConsoleKeyInfo info = Console.ReadKey();
if (info.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
{
    Console.WriteLine("You pressed enter!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    private void name(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == 13)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Pressed");                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach keydown event to a checkbox using Jquery and check for event.keycode == 13 (Enter):

```
var input = $("#textBox");
$(input).keydown(function (event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    alert("Enter!")
  }
});
```

Getting that to your c# is another thing as its not clear what framework you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to determine if the user presses an "Enter" key in a textBox, but you could apply this to anything really.

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    /* Check if the user hit the 'ENTER" key */
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Return)
    {
        /* Do Something */
    }
}
```